# nodejs fork child process without terminal (hidden)

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, child-process, pm2

Introduction: 
When invoking a child process with the fork() method, the child's output is connected to the master terminal and you can see the logs there. The specific command I use to fork a process is `fork(myScript.js, [aFewArguments])`. No options are specified.

Specific situation:
When I start the master node process without a terminal window using the command `pm2 start script.js` and then try to invoke a child process, a new terminal opens up for each forked process and thus pollutes the screen of the machine I am using.

I cannot find any information how to hide/remove the child process terminal from appearing.
Is there any way to hide/stop the child process terminals from opening?

Comment: Make sure you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861362/node-js-child-process-difference-between-spawn-fork)

Comment: I dont see how this is connected to hiding the terminal

Comment: Perhaps using `spawn()` and [`options.detached`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_detached) fixes it?