# Fork with async await in nodejs not working

Tags: node.js, async-await, child-process

I have tried to forking in node. For simple calculation it seems to work fine. But when I use for loop, I don't get any result. I have tried using promise also but all I get is promise pending. Below are the code used.

In moduleProgress.js:

```
const getModules = async (studentArray) => {
  let progress = [];
  for (const student of studentArray) {
    console.log(student); //prints the first student id an then nothing happens
    let std = await User.findById(student); //stops here
    console.log(std); //nothing
    std = {
      username: std.username,
      firstname: std.firstname,
      lastname: std.lastname,
      batch: std.batch,
    };
    progress.push(std);
  }
  return progress;
};

process.on("message", async (params) => {
  const progress = await getModules(params.students);
  process.send(progress);
});
```

In another file:

```
if (students.length > 0) {
        const calculation = fork("helpers/moduleProgress.js");
        calculation.send({
          students: students,
        });
        calculation.on("message", (response) => {
          allStatus = response;
          console.log(response)
        });
        res.json({
          success: true,
          allProgress: allStatus,
        });
```

Comment: I think you should consider using fork.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861362/node-js-child-process-difference-between-spawn-fork

Comment: @SrinathNilatech I have used fork. Or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Are you trying to run a child process or do you just want to run a function from another file at helpers/moduleProgress.js?

Comment: @SrinathNilatech I am trying to run a child process.

Comment: May I know where the fork is invoked because you have only shared a separate code.
It'll be great if you could share the code on github or stackblitz

Comment: @SrinathNilatech The fork is invoked in another file above. The const calculation part.

Comment: Okay, can you share the code? It'll be easier to debug that way

Comment: Meanwhile can i suggest you to use spawn instead of fork?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.
Called the instance of mongoose in the moduleProgress.js (child) and it worked as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the accepted solution, but I came here with a similar question about how to create a fork, send it a request, setup what to do with the response, and then wait until it completed.

For my solution, my child process code (moduleProgress.js in the example) looks the same, but then in the parent process that spawns the fork I used await with `once()` listening for the `exit` event and then in the function listening for a message, I called `kill()` on the child after processing it. I've updated the example, filling in a few details based on context like the method parameters:

```js
const { fork } = require('child_process');
const { once } = require('events');

exports.calculateProgress = async (req, res) => {
  const { students } = req;

  if (students.length > 0) {
    const calculation = fork("helpers/moduleProgress.js");
    calculation.send({
      students: students,
    });
    calculation.on("message", (response) => {
      allStatus = response;
      console.log(response)
      calculation.kill(); // Kill the child
    });
    await once(calculation, 'exit'); // Wait for the child to exit
    res.json({
      success: true,
      allProgress: allStatus,
    });
  }
}
```

I don't think this is the best solution for the given example since it seems likely you could just make the `res.json()` call inside the message event listener, but it solves the problem of wanting to wait for the child process to give a response.

My use case was originally using a child process to do a calculation asynchronously, but then I wanted to add metrics like a timer that could be combined with other metrics in the parent, so being able to utilize await came in handy.