# How can I run a js file from my nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I want to set up a server that scrapes data off an existing API, cleans it up and outputs it to my own server where I can manipulate the data further.

So far I've got all the pieces working.

- My server runs.
- I can scrape the data into the correct JSON format
- I have a function that runs when a POST https request is called that writes JSON to my database.

Now I need to connect the two.

There are 3 main components:

1. the server.js file
2. The Post controller & schema file. This contains the function that handles the http request and constructs the object and writes to the database.
3. I have a separate file that contains a bunch of functions that scrape the data and prepare it in the proper JSON format.

My problem is getting scraping file to run. At the moment to test it I just run Node filename.js it worked fine when I was outputting the json to console.log. However now I've written in the http request. the problem is, when I run the server to open the http endpoint, I can't run the file.js that contains the scraper.

Essentially I want the scraper to run on a schedule, and send the data to the endpoint I've set up on the server.

Is there a way to replicate calling `node filename.js` in code? As per my understanding when you run `node filename.js` it just runs down the file, executing code as it finds it. Is there a way to do this? Or do I need to call each function 1 by 1 from my server file? Or do I just encapsulate the whole js file in a master function (my worry would then be that variables become siloed)?

I've posted the code below for reference:

server.js

```
require("dotenv").config(); // ALLOWS ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES TO BE SET ON PROCESS.ENV SHOULD BE AT TOP

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const postRoutes = require("./routes/postRoutes.js");
const path = require('path');


// Middleware
app.use(express.json()); // parse json bodies in the request object

// Redirect requests to endpoint starting with /posts to postRoutes.js
app.use("/posts", postRoutes);

// Global Error Handler. IMPORTANT function params MUST start with err
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(err.stack);
  console.log(err.name);
  console.log(err.code);

  res.status(500).json({
    message: "Something went rely wrong",
  });
});

// Listen on pc port
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on PORT ${PORT}`));


const battlesGetData = require(path.resolve(__dirname, "./battlesgetData.js")); // is this right?!?
```

battlesGetData.js

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const postController = require("./controllers/postControllers");

//const fs = require('fs');


const distinct = (value, index, self) => {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

async function getBattleHistory(player = '', data = {}) {
    const battleHistory = await fetch('https://api2.splinterlands.com/battle/history?player=' + player)
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
            return response;
        })
        .then((battleHistory) => {
            return battleHistory.json();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('There has been a problem with your fetch operation:', error);
        });
    return battleHistory.battles;
}

const extractGeneralInfo = (x) => {
    return {
        created_date: x.created_date ? x.created_date : '',
        match_type: x.match_type ? x.match_type : '',
        mana_cap: x.mana_cap ? x.mana_cap : '',
        ruleset: x.ruleset ? x.ruleset : '',
        inactive: x.inactive ? x.inactive : ''
    }
}

const extractMonster = (team) => {
    const monster1 = team.monsters[0];
    const monster2 = team.monsters[1];
    const monster3 = team.monsters[2];
    const monster4 = team.monsters[3];
    const monster5 = team.monsters[4];
    const monster6 = team.monsters[5];

    return {
        summoner_id: team.summoner.card_detail_id,
        summoner_level: team.summoner.level,
        monster_1_id: monster1 ? monster1.card_detail_id : '',
        monster_1_level: monster1 ? monster1.level : '',
        monster_1_abilities: monster1 ? monster1.abilities : '',
        monster_2_id: monster2 ? monster2.card_detail_id : '',
        monster_2_level: monster2 ? monster2.level : '',
        monster_2_abilities: monster2 ? monster2.abilities : '',
        monster_3_id: monster3 ? monster3.card_detail_id : '',
        monster_3_level: monster3 ? monster3.level : '',
        monster_3_abilities: monster3 ? monster3.abilities : '',
        monster_4_id: monster4 ? monster4.card_detail_id : '',
        monster_4_level: monster4 ? monster4.level : '',
        monster_4_abilities: monster4 ? monster4.abilities : '',
        monster_5_id: monster5 ? monster5.card_detail_id : '',
        monster_5_level: monster5 ? monster5.level : '',
        monster_5_abilities: monster5 ? monster5.abilities : '',
        monster_6_id: monster6 ? monster6.card_detail_id : '',
        monster_6_level: monster6 ? monster6.level : '',
        monster_6_abilities: monster6 ? monster6.abilities : ''
    }
}

let battlesList = [];

  usersToGrab = ["rus48-bot", "sbalani"]

const battles = usersToGrab.map(user =>
    getBattleHistory(user)
        .then(battles => battles.map(
            battle => {
                const details = JSON.parse(battle.details);
                if (details.type != 'Surrender') {
                    if (battle.winner && battle.winner == battle.player_1) {
                        const monstersDetails = extractMonster(details.team1)
                        const info = extractGeneralInfo(battle)
                        return {
                            ...monstersDetails,
                            ...info,
                            battle_queue_id: battle.battle_queue_id_1,
                            player_rating_initial: battle.player_1_rating_initial,
                            player_rating_final: battle.player_1_rating_final,
                            winner: battle.player_1,

                        }
                    } else if (battle.winner && battle.winner == battle.player_2) {
                        const monstersDetails = extractMonster(details.team2)
                        const info = extractGeneralInfo(battle)
                        return {
                            ...monstersDetails,
                            ...info,
                            battle_queue_id: battle.battle_queue_id_2,
                            player_rating_initial: battle.player_2_rating_initial,
                            player_rating_final: battle.player_2_rating_final,
                            winner: battle.player_2,
                        }
                    }
                }

            })
        ).then(x => battlesList = [...battlesList, ...x])
)

Promise.all(battles).then(() => {
    const cleanBattleList = battlesList.filter(x => x != undefined)

    fetch("http://localhost:3000/posts/", {
        method: "post",
        body: cleanBattleList,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    })
        .then(json => console.log(json))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    
    /* fs.writeFile(`data/history.json`, JSON.stringify(cleanBattleList), function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }); */
});
```

This is the POST function that gets called

```
exports.createNewPost = async (req, res, next) => {

    /*
    let { summoner_id, summoner_level,
        monster_1_id, monster_1_level, monster_1_abilities,
        monster_2_id, monster_2_level, monster_2_abilities,
        monster_3_id, monster_3_level, monster_3_abilities,
        monster_4_id, monster_4_level, monster_4_abilities,
        monster_5_id, monster_5_level, monster_5_abilities,
        monster_6_id, monster_6_level, monster_6_abilities,
        created_date, match_type, mana_cap, ruleset, inactive,
        battle_queue_id, player_rating_initial, player_rating_final, winner
    } = req.body; // using postman this is what allows us to post JSON


    let post = new PostBattle(summoner_id, summoner_level,
        monster_1_id, monster_1_level, monster_1_abilities,
        monster_2_id, monster_2_level, monster_2_abilities,
        monster_3_id, monster_3_level, monster_3_abilities,
        monster_4_id, monster_4_level, monster_4_abilities,
        monster_5_id, monster_5_level, monster_5_abilities,
        monster_6_id, monster_6_level, monster_6_abilities,
        created_date, match_type, mana_cap, ruleset, inactive,
        battle_queue_id, player_rating_initial, player_rating_final, winner); // the title & body defined in the previous line taken from the JSON are now deposited here.
        */

    let json = req.body;

    for (var obj in json) {
        console.log(obj + ": " + json[obj]);

        let post = new PostBattle(json[obj].summoner_id, json[obj].summoner_level,
            json[obj].monster_1_id, json[obj].monster_1_level, json[obj].monster_1_abilities,
            json[obj].monster_2_id, json[obj].monster_2_level, json[obj].monster_2_abilities,
            json[obj].monster_3_id, json[obj].monster_3_level, json[obj].monster_3_abilities,
            json[obj].monster_4_id, json[obj].monster_4_level, json[obj].monster_4_abilities,
            json[obj].monster_5_id, json[obj].monster_5_level, json[obj].monster_5_abilities,
            json[obj].monster_6_id, json[obj].monster_6_level, json[obj].monster_6_abilities,
            json[obj].created_date, json[obj].match_type, json[obj].mana_cap, json[obj].ruleset, json[obj].inactive,
            json[obj].battle_queue_id, json[obj].player_rating_initial, json[obj].player_rating_final, json[obj].winner);
        console.log(post);

        //let post = new PostBattle(json);

        post = await post.save();

        console.log("a post is happening");
    }
```

Comment: You can [fork](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_processforkmodulepath-args-options) a new Node.js process. Your question is similar to [Node.js spawn child process and get terminal output live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332721/node-js-spawn-child-process-and-get-terminal-output-live)

Comment: This should also be helpful: [node.js child process - difference between spawn & fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861362/node-js-child-process-difference-between-spawn-fork)

Comment: THANK YOU FOR THIS! after some research I got it working! Thank you! Now I just need to figure out how to gracefully end the child fork so that the server doesn't stop when the script ends